# Pop an element from a linked list in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I've been trying to pop out an element from a linked list but I get this weird output.

This is the given skeleton code:

```
char* pop() {

}
```

and this is what I have for now:

```
char* pop() {
  char* val;
  struct node* current;

  if( head != NULL){   
        val = head -> name;
        current = head -> next;
        free(head);
        head = current;
    }

  return(val);
}
```

this is the main.c:

```
node *head = NULL; //globally accessible

int main(){
        printf("Printing an empty list\n");
        print_list();

        printf("\nPushing Kelsier...\n");
        push("Kelsier");
        print_list();

        printf("\nPushing Vin. Should be: Vin Kelsier\n");
        push("Vin");
        print_list();
        char* vin = pop();
        free(vin);
        pop();

        print_list();
```

here is the weird output:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./linked_list: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x000000000040098d ***
```

after this line is all some weird stuff and folder paths

the thing is that the program works without these two lines:

```
char* vin = pop();
free(vin);
```

when I replace them with only `pop();` , but these two lines are given and I'm not supposed to them.

This is push:

```
void push(char *name) {

        struct node* newNode;
        newNode =  malloc (sizeof (struct node));
        newNode->name = name;
        newNode->next = head;
        head = newNode;




}
```

Comment: You need to show the code that creates and inserts a new node into the list.  Or better yet, post a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: should be `char* val=NULL;`

Comment: And you need to show the definition of `struct node`. In particular is the `name` field a static array? If so, you cannot `free` it.

Comment: @Mossa Ahmed Show how you great list is declared.

Comment: Is that _all_ of your main.c? Where is the variable head initialized then?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I updates the post with most of main.c

Comment: @Mossa Ahmed You should show function push.

Comment: Use a debugger, like gdb.  Check that your data structure has the values you expect after you push a couple items.  Then check that it's still what you expect after a pop.  Narrow down to where things go from expected to unexpected.  You'll probably find the line of code with faulty logic, or that doesn't do what you thought it did.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I added push

Comment: Still no definition for struct node....

Comment: `free(vin);` : `free` can't use to string literal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pop` is returning the same pointer that was passed to `push`: the address of the string literal `"Vin"`.  You can't `free` a string literal, since you didn't get it from `malloc`.

If the values returned by `pop` are supposed to be `free`-able, then `push` will have to allocate a string rather than just copying a pointer.  For example, you might replace

```
newNode->name = name;
```

with

```
newNode->name = strdup(name);
```

Comment: Yeah.. we're still waiting for the OP to post the def. of struct node:(